# Replace text add text, but keep file name

Tags: vbscript, batch-file, rename

I am now 2 weeks busy with finding a good script. When I thought hey I have found my script, than things changed here at work. I need this script it's important for me. I hope someone could help me.

Each day a variable file name is downloaded with a date.

Example file of yesterday: *currency1.20121205*

Now I run a bat file with: `ren C:\blp\bbdl\_csv\* *?.csv`

File name is now *currency1.20121204.csv*

2 things have to happen:

1. Changing text inside the file : EUR to USD
2. Adding text at the end (I have found a script for this, but don't work with EUR on the beginning)

Text to add: *EUR CMPN Curncy|0|4|EUR||Composite(NY)|1.00000|*

What I have seen on the internet is that most scripts change the file name, but this has to stay the same.

Answer (score 0):

In batch you could try something like this:

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

cd C:\blp\bbdl\_csv

for %%f in (*) do (
  set file=%%f
  for /f %%l in (!file!) do (
    set line=%%l
    echo !line:EUR=USD! >> "!file!.csv"
  )
  echo EUR CMPN Curncy^|0^|4^|EUR^|^|Composite(NY)^|1.00000^| >> "!file!.csv"
)

endlocal
```

It'd be easier to do in VBScript, though:

```
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

For Each f In fso.GetFolder("C:\blp\bbdl\_csv").Files
  text = f.OpenAsTextStream().ReadAll
  Set f2 = fso.OpenTextFile(f.Path & ".csv", 2, True)
  f2.WriteLine Replace(text, "EUR", "USD")
  f2.WriteLine "EUR CMPN Curncy|0|4|EUR||Composite(NY)|1.00000|"
  f2.Close
Next
```

Both code snippets off the top of my head, so not tested.

Comment: I can use VBScript, i have tested it with script, but only 1 file has to be edited and not 4 files. On all 4 the files the line is added, and the euro to USD is changed. currency1.????????.csv had to be edited. on ?? there is the date, thats variable. Waiting for your response thanks

Comment: You need to define *which* file has to be edited, then. What distinguishes this file from the other files? Is it just the date part of the filename? Anything else?

Comment: Ansgar, how do i define that file. I am not a pro with scripts i can read it but i don't know how to. maybe i will try to edit this text = f.OpenAsTextStream().ReadAll

Comment: ok now someting else. i doing it diffrent. now the script is okey. but i need something.

Comment: the writline is added on the end. but i get a enter between. Can you edit it like the enter is removed. 

now i get this : 
RNEU CMPN Curncy|0|4|RON|12/06/2012|Composite(NY)|4.535200|
<<<this has to be deleted>>
EUR CMPN Curncy|0|4|EUR||Composite(NY)|1.00000|

Comment: @user1863225 You need to define criteria to select just the name of the file you want to modify. So what distinguishes this filename from the other filenames in that folder? Is it just the date? Is it the leading string `currency1.`? Anything else? To get rid of the spurious newline change `f2.WriteLine Replace(text, "EUR", "USD")` into `f2.Write Replace(text, "EUR", "USD")`.

Comment: it's this code : f2.WriteLine "EUR CMPN Curncy|0|4|EUR||Composite(NY)|1.00000|"  this is added on the end of the file, that's okey. But there is a enter above it. you get a empty line than EUR CMPN......

Comment: what i mean is someting else, the script is okey.  The last line is added by the script right ? But when the line EUR is added (not the change of EUR to USD) there is a empty line between the last line and the added "EUR CMPN Curncy|0|4|EUR||Composite(NY)|1.00000|". I need to empty the emty line(enters).

Comment: @user1863225: Did you do what I told you to do in my second-last response?

Comment: what you writed was replacing, what i responded was deleting a empty row. But the empty row is no issue anymore, i have found anothr script for it. But your script helped me very much, with out you i could not manage what i wanted. Thank you very much